# Storyboard Constraints set UIImageView no more than 50% of screen

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, storyboard, constraints

I have an `UIImageView` inside a `UIView`, I add 4 Constraints:

```
1) Top equal to top of the screen
2) center equal to center of screen
3) width equal to screen width 
4) aspect ratio of 1:1
```

The problem is that on `iPhone 11 Pro Max` it looks ok, but when I change to a smaller resolution the UIImageView is almost over all the screen, it's possible to define that the UIImageView will not be more than 50% of the screen?

[image] 
[image]
[image]

**EDIT**

---

[image]

And this is the result:
[image]

Comment: In storyboard choose the imageview, than on right panel choose Content Mode: aspect fit

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is ensure that the imageView does not exceed more than 50% of the enclosing view height-wise. But you can't guarantee that the horizontal edges will be pinned to the leading and trailing anchors.

Try something like this and see if it works for you:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.backgroundColor = .red

    view.addSubview(imageView)

    let dimension = min(view.frame.width, view.frame.height / 2)
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: dimension).isActive = true
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: dimension).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "height equal to screen height" constrain. Click on constrain, than change Multiplier = 0.5 . This will ensure that on any device the imageView height will be equal to half of the root view. [image]

Answer (score 0):

## Set 500 priority to equal width constraint than add less or equal constraint on height with 0.5 multiplier

[image]

#### Now it fits when screen is smaller

[image]

Comment: I tried it but i get big UIImageview as you can see in my post edit

Comment: Set 750 priority  to height. see on image